# How do you go about getting tiles in a 2d tilebased game?

Tags: java, arrays, object, 2d

I'm currently working on making a 2d tilebased game in java.
The way my game works right now is: Finding out which tiles are inside the screen area, then rendering these. The tiles are stored in an int array, where each tile is represented by a number.
For example 1 is grasstile and 2 is dirt tile. 
It uses a getTile method to decide what numbers is at the specific coordinates, then returns a tiletype based on what number is at that coordinate, example:

```
int[] tiles=new int[width*height];

if(tiles[x+y*width]==1) return grassTile;
else if(tiles[x+y*width==2]) return dirtTile;
else if..... and so on
```

But i'm wondering if it would be more efficient to make an array of tile objects?

```
Tile[] tiles=new Tile[mapWidth*mapHeight];

return tiles[x+y*width];
```

I'm wondering what is best performance wise?
Sorry if this is a bad question. I'm new to programming and I can't seem to find this anywhere else.
Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance cost of either of those methods is so positively tiny compared to the cost of doing graphical rendering that you really shouldn't care.  Instead of worrying about performance there, you should focus on writing clear, robust, extensible code.  With that in mind, I'd recommend:

1) Use a `Tile` class.  It will allow you to add much more than `tile_types` to them later on.

2) Use `new Tile[mapWidth][mapHeight]`, and address tiles as `tiles[x][y]`.  This approach costs more memory, and you will have to create all of the sub-arrays yourself, but it guards you against a lot of easy-to-make off-by-one errors, and other mathematical mistakes.